# Php session updating value at each new post from a form

Tags: php, forms, postgresql, session, post

I've just started recently to delve into the depths of html/php & co, so basically I'm a noob.

My question is simple: I'm using a php session to store a variable I'm using for an operation on the successive page. This variable is 'id' which is the primary key of my postgreSQL table. The user has a form on the web page in which it inserts the 'id' so as to select a particular row of the database to visualize and modify. Since the operations of visualization and modification are all in successive pages, I wanted the variable to remain memorized through the session (so that it's not required to post it again every time)

```
$_SESSION[id] = $_POST[id]
```

The problem arises when on a successive page I try to use a form to modify data on that particular row. I don't want the user to have to submit the 'id' again, so I use a select that involves $_SESSION[id]. But when the user submits the form, $_POST[id] is not specified in that form and its value goes to null. The result is that $_SESSION[id] is null and I cannot access the database using the query.

I found a way to solve the problem, but I find it extremely inelegant. I basically add a hidden section on the form that sends the id variable like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$_SESSION[id]">
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I really hope my question makes sense to you, feel free to comment for additional info.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The *inelegant* way is generally how you do it, though you don't store anything in session first you just use the values like the other fields. You should only be storing a csrf token in the session ;p

Comment: I am at a complete loss here, why do session values need to be carried over by the means of hidden fields when they are already in the session? `$_SESSION` itself with all values stored in it throughout the session should be available in your successive pages as long as your pages are php and have a call to `session_start()` on each.

Comment: I feel like the problem is in the fact that $_SESSION[id]=$_POST[id] so that when the user submits a new form (in which he is not asked for the id since he already selected it in the previous page), the variable $_POST[id] is non-existant and therefore the $_SESSION[id] is updated to null. I don't know if there's any way in which I can avoid $_SESSION[id]=$_SESSION[id] being re-run when i submit a new form.